# Getting all the children nodes of XML file to data.frame or data.table

Tags: r, xml

As example, I have the following XML code

```
tt = '<Nummeraanduiding>
  <identificatie>0010200000114849</identificatie>
<aanduidingRecordInactief>N</aanduidingRecordInactief>
<aanduidingRecordCorrectie>0</aanduidingRecordCorrectie>
<huisnummer>13</huisnummer>
<officieel>N</officieel>
<postcode>9904PC</postcode>
<tijdvakgeldigheid>
<begindatumTijdvakGeldigheid>2010051100000000</begindatumTijdvakGeldigheid>
</tijdvakgeldigheid>
<inOnderzoek>N</inOnderzoek>
<typeAdresseerbaarObject>Verblijfsobject</typeAdresseerbaarObject>
<bron>
<documentdatum>20100511</documentdatum>
<documentnummer>2010/NR002F</documentnummer>
</bron>
<nummeraanduidingStatus>Naamgeving uitgegeven</nummeraanduidingStatus>
<gerelateerdeOpenbareRuimte>
<identificatie>0010300000000444</identificatie>
</gerelateerdeOpenbareRuimte>
</Nummeraanduiding> '
```

The goal is to convert this node(Nummeraanduiding) to a data.table (or data.frame is also fine). One challenge is that I have a lot of these Nummeraanduiding nodes (millions of them).

The following code is able to process the data:

```
library(XML)
# This parses the doc...
doc = xmlParse(tt)
# Solution (1) - this is the most obvious solution..
XML::xmlToDataFrame(doc)
# Solution (2) - apparently converting to a list is also possible.. 
unlist(xmlToList(doc))
# Solution (3) - My own solution
data.frame(as.list(unlist(xmlToList(doc))))
```

Not all solutions produce the desired result... In the end only the version of Solution (3) satisfies my needs.

1. It is in a data.frame/data.table format
2. It contains all the child-child-nodes and has distinct names for each column
3. It does not 'merge' the information of child-child-nodes

However, running this piece of code for all my data becomes quite slow. It took 8+ hours to complete it for a file containing 2290000 times the 'Nummeraanduiding'-node.

Do you guys know any way to speed up this process? Can my method be improved? Am I missing some useful function maybe?

Comment: You could do it with xml2, e.g. `library(xml2) ; tt %>% read_xml() %>% xml_children() %>% {setNames(xml_text(.), xml_name(.))} %>% t() %>% data.frame()`, though I'd really probably leave off `t() %>% data.frame` and just `rbind` the vectors into a matrix that can be converted to a data.frame. If you want to parse the whole list element-wise, `purrr` can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Given that each field is already on a separate line just `grep` them out, read what is left using `read.table` and convert from long to wide using `tapply` to produce the resulting matrix (which can be converted to a data frame or data.table if desired).  Note that in `read.table` we bypass quote, comment and class processing.   Finally, test it out to see if it is faster.  No packages are used.

```
nms <- c("identificatie", "aanduidingRecordInactief", "aanduidingRecordCorrectie", 
"huisnummer", "officieel", "postcode", "tijdvakgeldigheid.begindatumTijdvakGeldigheid", 
"inOnderzoek", "typeAdresseerbaarObject", "bron.documentdatum", 
"bron.documentnummer", "nummeraanduidingStatus", 
"gerelateerdeOpenbareRuimte.identificatie")

rx <- paste(nms, collapse = "|")
g <- chartr("<", ">", grep(rx, readLines(textConnection(tt)), value = TRUE))

long <- read.table(text = g, sep = ">", quote = "", comment.char = "", 
  colClasses = "character")[2:3]
names(long) <- c("field", "value")
long$field <- factor(long$field, levels = nms)  # maintain order of columns
long$recno <- cumsum(long$field == "identificatie")

with(long, tapply(value, list(recno, field), c))
```

If all records have exactly the same set of fields, such as those listed in `nms`, then the last line could be replaced with this (which is likely faster):

```
matrix(long$value, ncol = length(nms), byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, nms))
```

Another alternative to the `tapply` line would be to use `reshape` from base R or to use `dcast` from the reshape2 package.